# Error Notice Array to string conversion after updating CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need help on below error

`Notice: Array to string conversion in /www/test_123/public/wp-content/plugins/test-functions/match-functions.php on line 302`

Below is written on 301 and 302 lines, I am not sure what is wrong. It is happening when I am updating the contact form 7 to latest version, but on 5.1.6 there is no such error.

```php
$location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
$p1_dob = $your_birth_year . "-" . $your_birth_month . "-" . $your_birth_day;
$p2_dob = $partners_birth_year . "-" . $partners_birth_month . "-" . $partners_birth_day;
$pmf_love_match_html_url = "https://primary.astrowebserver.net/v2/reports/CreateShortHTML/REL-NEW-DUALMATCH/?APIKEY=012bc72f-093a-4617-9432-0cbb55662ad7&P1FirstName=" . $your_first_name . "&P1DOB=" . $p1_dob . "&P1Sex=" . $your_gender . "&P1Country=" . $location['country'] . "&P2FirstName=" . $partners_first_name . "&P2DOB=" . $p2_dob . "&P2Sex=" . $partners_gender . "&P2Country=" . $location['country'];
```

Comment: strictly speaking its not an error but a notice. Use implode() function for proper converting array to string or otherwise identify the array element.

Comment: If these fields `$your_birth_year` and such are from contact form 7.  How are you getting the values of these fields, and are any of them selects (dropdowns) or checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending different variables into a `string`. Some of those variables are not of type `string` (but are instead an `array`), and thus cannot be appended to a string.

```php
$string_val = "foo";
$result = "-" . $string_val . "-" // works fine

$array_val = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
$result = "-" . $array_val . "-" // 'Notice: Array to string conversion ...'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but I am not very expert so can you let me know what to change in code in sent in my first message. Thanks

Comment: Print all variables you are using, and see which ones are not a string. Then, change those to the correct values.